# PHP send both http 1.0 and 1.1 headers

Tags: php, apache, http, http-headers, http-1.1

I see somewhere people doing something like:

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
?>
```

What's the purpose of this? Seems the second one will always overwrite the first header? 
Or is this because if some clients doesn't support http 1.1 so they can still receive a 1.0 header?

Comment: I can't think of any good reason to do that. If a client doesn't support HTTP 1.1 this century, very little on the web will work.

Comment: Do you mind showing us where you found this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no purpose to this.  Only one HTTP status line can be sent to the client.

The default is to send `200 OK` anyway, so unless you're overriding a previous status line (which would be strange), then both lines are pointless.

If you are using PHP 5.4+, you should use `http_response_code()` to set the status code anyway.  Leave the protocol implementation up to the web server.

Comment: What happens if a client request doesn't support 1.1 in this case? He gets   a null header or receive that 1.0 header?

Comment: @Zeyang It isn't a header, it's the status line.  It's a bit different than a header.  There will always be a status line.  What HTTP version used depends entirely on how the upstream server handles this sort of data.  It will vary from system to system.  You should test it in your specific configuration.  In practice, it won't matter since HTTP/1.1 is mostly backwards compatible with 1.0.

Comment: Right, I meant status line. Thanks for the in detail explanation.